# Visual Studio and Working with Team Member on the Same Database Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

We are currently starting to work with Visual Studio (2022) and work with 2 persons (later on it will be with the all the 4 team members) on a certain database project. Also, we use Git and have a bare repo containing the database project that has 4 branches: dev, tst, acc and main. If a developer wants to make a change to the data model, then he clones the repo and creates a change specific local branch. This branch is later on merged to the local dev branch and then pushed back to the remote dev branch (in the bare repo). Now this is not a version control issue, but I want to paint the complete picture here.

From VS we publish our database project to a development SQL server, which is used by the entire team. So if I make changes to table A, let's say add 3 columns and I publish them from VS to the development server, everything is fine. Now if my colleague creates table B and publishes his changes from VS to the development server, then this action causes the columns that I just created to be dropped.

I get that it works that way, but I am wondering how others way of working is to prevent this issue. Of course you want to work with the 4 team members in the same project if required and handle code conflicts via merge conflicts in Git, but I also want the other developers code to be not affected by me publishing my changes. If it is on the same table for example, ok. But if it is a different table for example, then I would prefer some sort of delta mechanism. I don't think this is possible in the way we are working now (using a central development server)? How do you do that to prevent this.

I thought of some solutions:

1. Merging your Git changes constantly -> Not a workable option
2. One person can work at a time -> Not a workable option
3. Everyone get's it's own development server -> My preference, but management doesn't like that probably. :-)
4. Maybe there is some way Visual Studio can be configured in order to handle changes in a different way?
5. Any other options?

I am really curious on how your team handles this. Later on we will start working with SSIS projects, which would cause packages get constantly overwritten from another?